# Truncate tokens for a topic model in MALLET

Tags: topic-modeling, text-analysis, mallet

I want to truncate all tokens in a corpus to have a maximum length of 5 characters. Is there a way to set the --token-regex import option in MALLET to accomplish this? The code I'm currently using to import documents is this:

```
mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet import-dir --input mallet-2.0.7/data/journals/ --output mallet-2.0.7/tmp/topic-input-journals.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --stoplist-file mallet-2.0.7/stoplists/tr.txt --token-regex '\p{L}[\p{L}\p{P}]*\p{L}'
```

If this is not possible in the MALLET import command, I’d appreciate suggestions on how to do the same in R.

Comment: **"I want to truncate all tokens to have a maximum length of 5 characters."** The previous sentence is the bottom-line of your question.  You'd have a higher chance for responses to your question if you took out the rest of the verbiage (as well as removed some of the tags).  And welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and the welcome. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify the token-regex so that it reads words of maximum 5 or n characters using this regular expression:

> \b\w{1,5}\b

where `\b` is a word boundary, `\w` is a word and `{1,5}` defines the minimum (1) and the maximum (5).

Your command line should be:

```
mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet import-dir --input mallet-2.0.7/data/journals/ --output mallet-2.0.7/tmp/topic-input-journals.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --stoplist-file mallet-2.0.7/stoplists/tr.txt --token-regex '\b\w{1,5}\b'
```

In Java:

```
pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{1,5}\\b")));
```

Hope this helps.